# Laravel - How to import excel file file and save into a table with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application. Also, I am using maatwebsite-3.1 to import excel file.

**Model: HrEmployee**

```
protected $table = 'hr_employees';

protected $fillable = [
          'employee_code',
          'user_id',
          'address',
          'company_id',
          'email',
          'line_manager_id',
          'employee_designation_id',
          'employee_job_title_id',
          'employee_status_id',
          'employee_type_id',
          'employement_type_id',
          'employment_date',
          'first_name',
          'last_name',
      'is_hod'
      ];

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('HrEmployee', 'line_manager_id');
}

public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany('HrEmployee', 'ine_manager_id');
}

public function company()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany','company_id');
}

public function designation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrDesignation','employee_designation_id');
}

public function jobtitle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrJobTitle','employee_job_title_id');
}

public function employeestatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployeeStatus','employee_status_id');
}

public function employeetype()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployeeType','employee_type_id');
}

public function employementtype()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployementType','employement_type_id');
}

public function department()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgDepartment','department_id');
}
```

I have already configured the Maatwebsite Excel Package

**app/Imports/EmployeesImport.php**

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use App\HrEmployee;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class EmployeesImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
  public function model(array $row)
  {
    return new HrEmployee([
        'employee_code'     => $row['employee_code'],
        'email'    => $row['email'], 
        'first_name'    => $row['first_name'],
        'last_name'    => $row['last_name'],
        'line_manager_id'    => $row['line_manager_id'],
        'employee_designation_id'    => $row['employee_designation_id'],
        'employee_job_title_id'    => $row['employee_job_title_id'],
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class HrEmployeesController extends Controller
{
  public function importExportView()
  {
     return view('import');
  }

  public function import() 
  {
    Excel::import(new EmployeesImport,request()->file('file'));

    return back();
  }
}
```

[image: excel sample]

How do I re-write my code to accommodate the foreign  keys (line_manager_id,employee_designation_id,employee_job_title_id), so that it will map the keys to the name.
For example, if designation_name is entered to the excel sheet it should map it to employee_designation_id.

Thank you

Comment: can you show the example of excel row?

Comment: @muhammad - I have added the excel sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the foreign key ID in the `EmployeesImport`

```
$row['employee_designation_id'] = HrDesignation::where("name", "like", "%".$row['designation']."%");
$row['line_manager_id']         = HrEmployee::where("first_name", "like", "%".$row['line_manager']."%");
$row['employee_job_title_id']   = HrJobTitle::where("name", "like", "%".$row['job_title']."%");
```

or the full code

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use App\HrEmployee;
use App\Hr\HrDesignation;
use App\Hr\HrJobTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class EmployeesImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $row['employee_designation_id'] = HrDesignation::where("name", "like", "%".$row['designation']."%");
        $row['line_manager_id']         = HrEmployee::where("first_name", "like", "%".$row['line_manager']."%");
        $row['employee_job_title_id']   = HrJobTitle::where("name", "like", "%".$row['job_title']."%");

        return new HrEmployee([
            'employee_code'           => $row['employee_code'],
            'email'                   => $row['email'],
            'first_name'              => $row['first_name'],
            'last_name'               => $row['last_name'],
            'line_manager_id'         => $row['line_manager_id'],
            'employee_designation_id' => $row['employee_designation_id'],
            'employee_job_title_id'   => $row['employee_job_title_id'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use App\HrEmployee;
use App\Hr\HrDesignation;
use App\Hr\HrJobTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class EmployeesImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $employee_designation = HrDesignation::where("name", "like", "%".$row['designation']."%")->first();
        $line_manager = HrEmployee::where("first_name", "like", "%".$row['line_manager']."%")->first();
        $employee_job_title   = HrJobTitle::where("name", "like", "%".$row['job_title']."%")->first();

        $row['employee_designation_id'] = $employee_designation->id;
        $row['line_manager_id'] = $line_manager->id;
        $row['employee_job_title_id'] = $employee_job_title->id;

        return new HrEmployee([
            'employee_code'           => $row['employee_code'],
            'email'                   => $row['email'],
            'first_name'              => $row['first_name'],
            'last_name'               => $row['last_name'],
            'line_manager_id'         => $row['line_manager_id'],
            'employee_designation_id' => $row['employee_designation_id'],
            'employee_job_title_id'   => $row['employee_job_title_id'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.